# `Thur, Aug 23` Date format with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

According to [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html), it seems that it is only possible to manipulate dates with a numeric format, and not letters.

Does a package exist if I want to display date with the format `Thur, Aug 23` ?
If not, how could I do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have a look at the intl package: https://pub.dev/packages/intl#date-formatting-and-parsing

Comment: try this in date format "EEEE, MMM d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `DateFormat` using it's default constructor.

The format you want is `EEEE, MMM d`.

For Example `print(new DateFormat("EEEE, MMM d").format(new DateTime.now()));` should print `Wedn, Jun 26` for today.